# Half of voltage on GPIO when using external pull-up

Tags: raspberry-pi, switching, pullup, button, push-pull

[image]I added a pull-up resistor to GPIO in order to use the reed switch.
You can see the wiring in the picture I attached. It works but I'm confused why when I wire multimeter to PB0 and GND it shows about 1,62 voltage. Why is that? Did I make something wrong? Can I leave it like it is, allowing it to operate on a lower voltage than 3.3V? What may be the consequences? [image]

VCC1 is the VCC I use to power the engine that the board controls, whereas the VCC2 is the VCC provided by Raspberry Pi Zero.

EDIT:
One thing just came to my mind. I have configured also a programmable pullup, as the previous solution relayed on the internal pull-up but I have changed it to hardware pull-up, but the internal pullup remains enabled. Does it matter?

EDIT:
I uploaded a new schematic, which reflects the actual wiring, because I'm using two sensors.

On R14 and R15 I've got a voltage drop about 1,60V.

Comment: Two pullups connected together still pull the signal up just fine. What's the voltage drop across R13?

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Are the grounds (Vcc1 ground & Vcc2 ground) at the same potential?

Comment: Is there a reason for the diodes? Are there humans that will be touching this circuit?

Comment: Is anything else connected to PB0 when you make these measurements?

Comment: @yay yes, they have the same potential

Comment: @Voltage Spike: probably no one will be touching this, but it was suggested to me to add them.

Comment: @Eliot Alderson: No, I even disconnected it from the Rpi.

Comment: Where exactly do you have the voltage drop? R13 and R14 can't drop the same voltage. Tell us the voltage across each of them individually.

Comment: I removed D11 diode, and on PB0 (I added two PB0s by mistake) next to the R16 I've got 3.3V. Why is that?

Comment: I checked it, but for me it seems to be kinda weird, because the voltage drop was about 20-30mV.

Comment: What's the voltage at VCC1?

Comment: For the testing purpose I disabled voltage at VCC1. Power supply is just disabled. Normally there is 12V.